# When should one group around-actions into the same aspect and when should one create different aspects?

Tags: java, aop

I'm currently studying **Aspect-Oriented Programming** and while I was trying to practice a little bit, I realised I was designing different methods in the same aspect and I started wondering if this is the best way to do it, or if I should create different aspects for different methods.
I'll try to explain more what I did:
I had 2 classes:

1. **Calculator** Class had several methods such ass add, multiply, negate, reset, etc.
2. **AOPmain** Class.

I created another class ( **ReturnMessage** class) to be an **aspect**, and in this class I created 2 methods - as you can see in the code below) (One is applied in a half of the methods found in the **Calculator** class, and the second one for some of the other methods in that same class - **Calculator**).
My question is: is it a good practice, to write several methods in an aspect to interact with other methods or it would be better to create different aspects for it?
Here is the code of my **aspect**:

```
@Aspect
public class ReturnMessage {
    //the joinPoint is used to get the method names and args.
    @Before("execution(public void *(double))")
    public void returningMessage( JoinPoint jp) {
        String method = jp.getSignature().getName();
        double value = (Double) jp.getArgs()[0];
        System.out.println("Going to "+method+" "+value);
    }
    @Before("@annotation(lala)")
    public void returnMsg2(MyAnnotation lala) { //<-- should I create another aspect to put this method?
        System.out.println(lala.msg());
    }
}
```

I believe it'll be interesting not only for me, but for all users of stackoverflow who are starting programming in aop, so I hope you guys to be pacient.

Comment: I am totally confused which classes are being advised, which classes are aspects what you mean by "interact" in "write several methods in an aspect to interact with other methods". Perhaps you can names instead of saying one class, other class, another class etc

Comment: "Is it a good practice to ..." questions are most often answered "sometimes".  If you want advice on when to do x instead of y, you should ask "When should I do x instead of y?"  Would answers to "When should one group around-actions into the same aspect and when should one create different aspects?" be as useful as your current question?

Comment: Yes @MikeSamuel, I'll take your note as example. Sorry for the way I asked and I agree with you. The quality of SO needs to be kept high-level, but don't you agree that people.

Comment: @MiserableVariable, I'll try to edit to make it more understandable

Comment: @periback2, "but don't you agree that people." ???

Comment: sorry.. i published without the rest of the sentence.. I was saying: "don't you agree that people searches for best practices?" I mean.. I agree with what u say.. totally, but the question was understandable and I believe people also found it interesting, and the way the title was set before, we would have more possibility to find people who knows something about the subject (maybe they woudn't know the aswer, but they could be curious too)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would create an Aspect for each cross cutting concern i want to track.  It is ok, to have multiple pointcut/method in your aspect.

You could have an Aspect responsible for logging, one for metrics etc...

I found this link very helpful when i worked with AoP to measure the perf. of an existing app.

It talk about aspect over existing codebase, but the it can be applied  to any case.

[Applying AspectJ to an Existing Codebase](http://www.rossenstoyanchev.org/write/prog/eclipse/eclipse5.html)

Answer (score 1):

Even if they aren't conventional Objects, Aspects are software components are should respect the principles of good design - including [high cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GRASP_%28object-oriented_design%29#High_Cohesion). I'm no AspectJ expert, but I'd say that high cohesion is the most important thing to bear in mind when deciding if you want to add a method to your aspect.

Aspect oriented programming already has the potential to make execution paths a little more obscure, so I don't think separating each and every methods into its own aspect would be a good idea. It would lead to many games of "dude where's my code" for future devs working in the same system. I think it would be a better idea to group methods together in an Aspect so they're easier to find.

Answer (score 1):

An `aspect` is also a `class` and as others have answered it should consist of related functionality. To paraphrase Cygnusx1, you don't want a single aspect to have advices for logging as well as generating metrics.

Further organization may be required on the basis of the pointcuts they are targeting. For example, consider that the `Logger` aspect generates multiple different of logs, e.g. terse and verbose.

It would make sense to create this aspect in the package `com.company.project.logging`. But do you want it to refer to *all* the places in code that need to be advised? Probably not.

What I would do is to create an *abstract aspect* and extend that contains concrete advises and abstract named point-cuts. I would then extend this with concrete aspects in various packages `com.company.project.dataaccess`, `com.company.project.purchase` etc which implement those abstract pointcuts.

So what I have done is exposed an aspect that does logging and allowed individual module owners to define when these should be triggered.